# How to hide ribbon for everyone only on 1 custom NewForm.aspx?

Tags: ribbon

I am using sp2010. I have cloned a NewForm.aspx and replace some button with my own submit button. I would like to hide the ribbon on this custom NewForm.aspx page. All other pages needs to stay like they are inclusive ribbon.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the page in designer. Place below CSS inside AdditionalPageHead placeholder

```
<style type="text/css">
    #s4-ribbonrow { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Or just add a cewp or script editor web part and do the same thing